# How to keep models updated for all users connected through websockets in AngularJS?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, synchronization, websocket

(I don't think it belong to Programmers, but to stackoverflow, since it uses real world modules and libraries, IMHO)

I'm trying to figure out how can I keep models updated for all connected users at a certain page. For the sake of an example (don't have a POC working code at the moment), I'm using AngularJS along with Primus module on Node.js. I started a repo for a plugin for usage with both Primus and AngularJS available in https://github.com/pocesar/angular-primus/issues/1#issuecomment-23685634

So, I was thinking about doing incremental updates to the server, and full-on model rewrite for every connected client. Since the client needs to know exactly the current state of the model on the server side, to apply "patches" from client to the server would be cumbersome.

Imagine there are 3 people at the page, each independent from each other, but of course, their models structure are identical. For illustration, think the app as a collaborative "TODO" list, that some items are public and some items are private. The public items should be broadcast to all connected clients in realtime, while still maintaining private items to each user. The server keeps the listing (public and private) for each user. Using, for example, a map reduce, you could filter out all public items from all models from all users, and send them everytime to the 3 connected users. This is bandwidth intensive, and might not be the best for like 10000 concurrent connected users. This would defeat the websocket use, since I could just achieve the same using AJAX and poll it from time to time.

The thing I'm trying to conceive is how to keep both sides (client and server) updated with the lastest information, and still maintain the integrity, since the server can receive anything from the client, but it's up to the server to send to other clients the information.

I thought of using, for example, https://github.com/benjamine/JsonDiffPatch that can diff Javascript objects, so I can send only the changed part of the models. Another thing is that I keep the last modification date on each model and compare from the timestamps of newly 'pushed' data, so I can only grab/accept what was new. Another option would create a hash for the current model, and only compare hashes instead of values... So what else is out there? What are the flaws in my current conception?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just detect an addition to the model on the server side and send a socket message from the server to each client if some condition (public/private) on the server is true.

Client receives the change and updates the model with only the new object.

If you want, happy to talk you through some code and walk through architecture in more detail here
https://www.sudonow.com/session/52570cab55ef31161e000005